# How to disable update button in yii2?

Tags: yii, yii2

I have access control like this in my controller:

```
public function behaviors()
 {
return [
   'access'=>[
            'class' => AccessControl::className(), 
            'only'=>['view','index'],
            'rules'=>[
                [    
                    'allow'=>true,
                    'actions'=>['view','index'],
                    'roles'=>['@'],
                ]
             ],
    ],
    ];
}
```

If I use that code, it'll be possible to update data records. But what I need right now is how to disable the update button? When we click update, it'll be said forbidden. How to make that? Thanks in advance

Comment: What update button are you talking about? Where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `update` action to the array of actions affected by AccessControl rules:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
       'access'=>[
            'class' => AccessControl::className(), 
            'only' => ['view', 'index', 'update'],
            'rules' => [
                [    
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => ['view', 'index'],
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ]
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

This way the rules will also apply to `actionUpdate` and because there is no rule giving access to any role to `update` when trying to access it you will get a 403 forbidden error.